# Excel VBA - Deleting Cells via radio button and restoring the content if other radio button clicked

Tags: excel, vba

I would like some help with excel VBA please as I'm just unsure how to do this and couldn't find anything to guide me.

I have 2 radio button, 1st is "In" and 2nd is "Out".

What I am trying to do is. If "Out" is clicked, cells `D9:D20` are deleted and cells on the right will shift left.

If you click "In", I would like the original content to come back (think of it like you've clicked Undo-Last (Ctrl+Z)

The purpose is, I am trying to build a smarter form for someone in our business that will have the fields change based on what activity you are doing.

Comment: Sounds straightforward enough.  The first step is to forget about the radio buttons for now, and get the "guts" of it working.  Making it button-activated is an afterthought.  Have you attempted this yet? - can you share your code?

Comment: I am curious what you're trying to accomplish, "end goal"  -- obviously if the user make other changes after deleting the data, it may not be recoverable... is that a problem or is this data easily regenerated?  Perhaps it would be better to just Hide/Unhide the appropriate columns/rows?

Comment: I tried to hide column but because I have merged cells it destroys the format of the entire sheet. I am very novice in VBA (self learning).
The 'end goal' is that this is going to be used as a form. I want that cell range deleted as it is not applicable if their activity is "Out" selected by a radio button. If their activity is "In" then that cell range and it's header is made available/visible. Apologies again if I am not making sense, I don't have code to share as I simply don't know what I am doing to attempt it.

Comment: A lot of this is quite simple and can be done with recorded macros at the core. On clicking out then copy the range to a 'trashcan' sheet and delete the range on the main sheet.
On clicking 'in' and if the 'trashcan' is not empty then copy and insert the trashcan range into the main sheet and delete the 'trashcan' range.

Comment: What do you need help with, exactly? You want to know how to delete a cell? How to undo the last command? How to insert a cell? How to associate code with a button? How to call a subroutine when the value of a form field changes?

Comment: @AndyW That's a great suggestion and shouldn't be too hard to figure out. I'll try that and get back to you all. Thank you.

Comment: @AndyW I got it to work this way, thanks for the suggestion (should have thought of that)